# How to get a subsequence of items across multiple lists from a list of lists?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, nested, subsequence

I am trying to get subsequence of items between 2 lists in a list of lists. For example, if I have

```
list=[[1,2,3,4],[],[6,9],[2],[3],[4]]
```

I want to extract the items ranging from `list[0][1]` until `list[2][1]` into another list. This resulting list would then be `[2,3,4,6]` (ignoring the empty list in between).

How can I do that? I have been trying to use a `for i in range(...)` loop but it is not working for me.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming your list is called `list_of_lists`<sup>**1**</sup>, this [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) using [`enumerate()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate) works:

```
[n for i, sub_list in enumerate(list_of_lists)
   for j, n in enumerate(sub_list)
   if (0, 1) <= (i, j) < (2, 1)]
```

<sup>**1**</sup> It's a bad idea to call a list `list` as in your example, because that masks the name of the type `list`, which you then don't have access to.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
def complex_slice(my_list, i, j, k):
    result = my_list[i][k:]
    for sub_list in my_list[ (i + 1) : (j - 1) ]:
        result.extend(sub_list)
    result.extend(my_list[j][:k])
    return result
```